# Add another element using GetElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tablerow

Let's say that this' an HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Wusool</td>
    <td id="yasel">
        15:12 
    </td>
</tr>
```

and I want to change it into this html code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Wusool</td>
    <td id="yasel">
        15:12 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ersal</td>
    <td id="sent">
        20:12
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I use GetElementById to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tr = document.getElementById('yasel').parentNode,
    new_tr = tr.parentNode.insertRow( tr.rowIndex + 1 ),
    new_td;

new_tr.insertCell(0).innerHTML = 'Erasel';

(new_td = new_tr.insertCell(1)).innerHTML = '20:12';
new_td.id = "sent";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7N3kr/

Answer (score 0):

After getting elementbyID, get parent element (I don't have code handy, but you can google how to get parent element for html getelementbyID). Then add child element.

Comment: There's the attribute `parentNode`: `document.getElementById('id').parentNode` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code in HTML Head:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function ChangeValue(element_id, val) {
        var elm = document.getElementById(element_id);
        elm.innerHTML = val;
    }
</script>
```

Try This in HTML body:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="box1"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="box2"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="box3"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn_change1" value="Change Value" onclick="ChangeValue('box1','22:30')" />
<input type="button" id="btn_change2" value="Change Value" onclick="ChangeValue('box2','11:10')" />
<input type="button" id="btn_change3" value="Change Value" onclick="ChangeValue('box3','21:35')" />
```

Comment: Did you post your answer under the right question? Seems like you're answering an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can do it as

```
var td_elem = document.getElementById('yasel');
var tr_elem = td_elem.parentNode;
var table_elem = tr_elem.parentNode;

table_elem.innerHTML = table_elem.innerHTML + '<tr><td>Ersal</td><td id="sent">20:12</td></tr>';
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4MJuS/

but you must try using jquery, it is a very good framework for javascript.
you can do it vary easily using jQuery

```
$('#yasel').parent().parent().append('<tr><td>Ersal</td><td id="sent"> 20:12 </td></tr>');
```

Comment: You really shouldn't do stuff like `table_elem.innerHTML = table_elem.innerHTML + '<tr><td>...'`. It is terribly destructive an requires much more overhead than needed.